# better way to write queries with 2 selection criteria

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a web app where database query comes from two selection boxes, one is about `sex` and the other is about `class_type`. In my code, I have a base query which has the following form

```
q = User.query.with_entities(*(getattr(User, col) for col in cols))
```

And depending on whether `sex` and `class_type` are chosen to be `all`, I break the cases as follows

```
if sex=='all' and class_type=='all':
    rows = q.all()
elif sex=='all' and class_type!='all':
    rows = q.filter_by(class_type=class_type)
elif sex!='all' and class_type=='all':
    rows = q.filter_by(sex=sex)
else:
    rows = q.filter_by(sex=sex, class_type=class_type)
```

Is there a better way to write this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
filters = {}
if sex != 'all':
    filters['sex'] = sex
if class_type != 'all':
    filters['class_type'] = class_type
rows = q.filter_by(**filters)
```

You would only need one condition per attribute, and an empty dictionary for `filters` would result in a query with no `WHERE` clause.